# Is it easier to get a foreign medical degree (MBBS) recognized in Australia than in Germany?

Tags: germany, medicine, australia, accreditation

Is it easier to get an MBBS degree recognized in Australia than in Germany?

Answer (score 3):

This is, regrettably, an incomplete answer to your question. The place to start your enquiries about Australia are with the [Medical Board of Australia](https://www.medicalboard.gov.au/).  The process of accrediting graduates of foreign medical schools is well documented on the website of the Medical Board. In particular, you need the page for "[Assessment pathways to registration for international medical graduates](https://www.amc.org.au/check-eligible-medical-school-medical-degrees-and-graduation-years/)" which sets out the various pathways to accreditation.

You will also want to take an early look at the [page](https://www.amc.org.au/check-eligible-medical-school-medical-degrees-and-graduation-years/) that lists all the medical schools around the world whose degrees might be recognized by the Medical Board.  That page has a drop-down list from which you can select the country wherein you graduated, presumably Pakistan given your first paragraph. If your medical school appears when you choose the correct country, then you have cleared the first hurdle. There is still a long way to go, but at least the process in well described.

I have no knowledge of the German (or European Union?) accreditation system and, even if you find someone who can give you detailed information on the accreditation process in Germany, I think it unlikely that you will find anyone who can make a direct comparison between the Australian process and the German process. You are likely to have to make that assessment yourself.

Good luck.